# Downloading a file from laravel storage using saved url in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my code to save a file in laravel storage folder and the file url in mysql database.

```
$summary_attachment = $request->file('claimSummary');
$new_summary_attachment = time().$summary_attachment->getClientOriginalName();
$summary_attachment_path = $request->file('claimSummary')->storeAs('uploads', $new_summary_attachment);
$attachment_path = Storage::url($summary_attachment_path);
$individual_application->summary_attachment = $attachment_path;
$individual_application->save();
```

Anf this is my view file where I am retrieving the url of the file and giving the url as a value to href in anchor tag.

```
<a href="{{ $application->summary_attachment }}" download target="_blank">Claim Summary</a>
```

But nothing happens when I click the link. When I hover over the link, the url is displayed in the bottom. But it doesn't show any errors. Just nothing happens when I click the link. When I right click, use copy url and paste it in new tab, the file is downloading. Just nothing happens when I click the link. Could somebody please mention what am I missing here. Please help.

Comment: Do you want the link to download or open a new browser tab (`target="_blank"`)? Do not combine both attributes.

Comment: I want the link to download. I tried removing the 'target="_blank"' attribute. Still the problem persists.

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger. Check for errors.

Comment: Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. Error 403. Could you please share me a solution for this. Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `href`?

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/casems/storage/app/uploads/1625637473ReportAndAnalysisForPrinciple.docx. This the value of href.

Comment: The value of `$application->summary_attachment` is an absolute file system path and not the result from `Storage::url($summary_attachment_path);`.

Comment: Did you correctly setup `storage/app/public` (symbolic link)? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Yes I created the symbolic link using the php artisan storage:link command. And I am using Storage::path() method instead of Storage::url() because while using Storage::url(), i get no file error.

Comment: You cannot send the client `Storage::path()` because web browsers cannot directly access the local file system and the path sent to the client is the webserver's file system path even if you are running the webserver and client on the same system (XAMPP).

Comment: So what do you suggest I do. Because Storage::url() methos is only saving this 'http://localhost/storage/uploads/1625639932On%20a%20hot%20summer%20night.docx' in the database. And while downloading i get Faile- no file error.

Comment: `Storage::url()` is the correct method. You have another problem, but without details, I can only guess. Use the Chrome debugger and the Laravel logfile to figure out why `http://localhost/storage/uploads/1625639932On%20a%20hot%20summer%20night.docx` does not work.